# MongoDB/Mongoose Schema for checking room availability

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I've following schema for a Hotel room.

```
    const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

    const reservationSchema = new Schema({
      checkIn: {
        type: Date,
        require: true
      },
      checkOut: {
        type: Date,
        require: true
      },
      status: {
        type: String,
        require: true,
        enum: ['pending', 'cancel', 'approved', 'active', 'completed']
      }
    });

    const roomSchema = new Schema(
      {
        title: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        },
        slug: {
          type: String
        },
        description: {
          type: String,
          required: true
        },
        capacity: {
          adults: {
            type: Number,
            required: true
          },
          childs: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
          }
        },
        roomPrice: {
          type: Number,
          required: true
        },
        gallery: [
          {
            type: String,
            require: true
          }
        ],
        featuredImage: {
          type: String,
          require: true
        },
        reservations: [reservationSchema],
        isAvailable: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: true
        },
        isFeatured: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false
        },
        isPublish: {
          type: Boolean,
          default: false
        }
      },
      { timestamps: true }
    );

module.exports = model('Room', roomSchema);
```

Now I want to find rooms which are not reserved for a particular date period.

Example: If the search query is checkIn: 12/25/2019 and checkOut:12/30/2019 then the query result will show that rooms which are not reserved for this period. Also, it will show the reserved room if the reservation status is canceled.

How can I achieve this?
Do I need to change the Schema design for achieving this?

Comment: @SuleymanSah Yeah If a reservation status: cancel then the date will show available.

Comment: Please share input data and output at jsoneditor online